# Is Java is purely object oriented language as we run main method without creating Object?

Tags: java

In many of the book says that "java is purely object oriented language".
i wont accept that, because we can run the program without using object since static methods and members can be used without creating object.

Comment: who says `java is purely object oriented language`?

Answer (score 4):

Java is not pure OOP language, because, it's has primitives. To be a pure OO language, it should only have objects. [Smalltalk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk) is a OO language

Answer (score 0):

Java is not a pure object oriented language because it supports Primitive datatype such as int, byte, long… etc, to be used, which are not objects.

There are seven qualities to be satisfied for a programming language to be pure Object Oriented which are as follows:

1. Encapsulation/Data Hiding
2. Inheritance
3. Polymorphism
4. Abstraction
5. All predifined types are objects
6. All operations are performed by sending messages to objects
7. All user defined types are objects.

For point number 5:
Primitive types, try this:
int i = 12;
System.err.println(i.toString());

Java is not pure OO Language.
Pure OO Language is C#.